# Change all "go-to mark" mappings

Tags: vimrc

I find that:

```
``
```

Is much more useful to me than:

```
''
```

And same with:

```
`.
```

Vs:

```
'.
```

(Sorry for the odd code-formatting, I had trouble doing the ``-formatting inline)

Is it possible to set a vimrc remap such that whenever I type in one of the 'go-to marks, such as `''` it does the `-equivalent? I.e., something like:

```
:nnoremap ''     ``
```

But for all of the go-to marks.

Comment: what about `nnoremap ' \``?

Comment: @Mass sure -- is `'` ever used for anything else in vim? If not, I think the above would work (I'm a novice so wasn't sure).

Comment: I dont think it can be based on `:help '`